# Setup.py woes: WARNING: '' not a valid package name

Tags: python, pypi

For my Python project, I keep my source code in the directory `src`. Thus, for my project's setup.py script:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(name='pyIAST',
    ...
    package_dir={'':'src'},
    packages=[''])
```

so that it looks for `src/IAST.py`, where my code resides. e.g. there is a function `plot_isotherms()` in my `IAST.py` script so the user can, after installation, call it:

```
import IAST
IAST.plot_isotherms()
```

Everything works great, but there is an annoying warning when I `python setup.py install` or use `pip install pyIAST` from PyPi:

```
WARNING: '' not a valid package name; please use only.-separated package names in setup.py
```

How do I make this go away?

My project is [here](https://github.com/CorySimon/pyIAST). I'm also a bit confused as to why I name my package `pyIAST`, yet the user still types `import IAST` for my package to import.

Comment: Did you try giving it a valid package name?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams setuptools.setup comes from distutils.core.setup. distutils docs show that `''` is a valid package. I guess the setuptools extention breaks this though. https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/examples.html#pure-python-distribution-by-package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to clear that warning is to change your first line to:
`from setuptools import setup, find_packages`
and then change your packages line to:
`packages=find_packages(),`
The setup install will no longer generate a warning.

You can run the following two commands to see your isotherm method is now available:
`import pyiast`  #(<==notice this is not IAST)
`dir(pyiast)`

> `['BETIsotherm', 'InterpolatorIsotherm', 'LangmuirIsotherm', 'ModelIsotherm', 'QuadraticIsotherm', 'SipsIsotherm', '_MODELS', '_MODEL_PARAMS', '_VERSION', '__author__', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', 'iast', 'np', 'plot_isotherm', 'print_selectivity', 'reverse_iast', 'scipy']`

It can be called using `pyiast.plot_isotherm()`

You may need to update your setuptools. You can check what version you have with:
`import setuptools; print "setup version: ", setuptools.__version__`
Can update it with: 
`sudo pip install --upgrade setuptools`